# If I use Mailgun with Laravel for a webform, who do I get my email account from, my DNS provider or my host provider?

Tags: email, laravel-5, mailgun, forge, namecheap

I have a website setup using Laravel which uses a webform for visitors to send email to me.  I use Mailgun as the driver.  I have my domain registered with Namecheap.  They said they are my DNS provider.  I set up my website using Forge and DigitalOcean.

I have two email accounts with Namecheap's Private Email subscription.  The instructions at Mailgun told me to change the setting from Private Email at Namecheap to use MX Records.  When I did that I was able to get Mailgun working but I no longer could use the email accounts I had with Namecheap.  Essentially what Namecheap is saying is that I can't have email addresses with my domain and use Mailgun at the same time.  They said it is because I can't have both my email addresses and Mailgun configured on one domain.  That can't be true.

What do I need to do to set up email addresses with my domain and use Mailgun as my email driver with Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup mailgun for a subdomain different than `yourdomain.com` or`mail.yourdomain.com`. For example we setup our transactional mails with the `auto-mailer.ourdomain.com` addresses. This way you can use both.

After adding the domain in Mailgun you need to set the proper DNS records listed at `https://app.mailgun.com/app/domains/auto-mailer.yourdomain.com` (Replace `yourdomain` with your real one.) After this you will be able to send emails via Mailgun and recive/send emails with your Private Mail subscription.

If you want to receive emails from mailgun you can set up a catch-all rule at the [Routes tab](https://app.mailgun.com/app/routes) of Mailgun admin.